# Почему не работает CSS на сайте с единой точкой входа?

Tags: php, .htaccess, редирект

Вопрос прост: не работает CSS, как исправить? Когда открываю сам CSS-файл через браузер - ничего не выдает.
Index.php

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/'){
    $Page = 'index';
    $Module = 'index';
}  else {
    $URL_Path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $URL_Parts = explode('/', trim($URL_Path, ' /'));
    $Page = array_shift($URL_Parts);
    $Module = array_shift($URL_Parts);

    if(!empty($Module)){
        $Param = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($URL_Parts); $i++){
            $Param[$URL_Parts[$i]] = $URL_Parts[++$i];
        }
    }
}

if($Page == 'index' and $Module == 'index') include 'main.php';
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options All -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^resource/(.*)$ resource/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Где вы подключили файл css к вашей страничке/сайту?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Kube CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/kube.css">
    <style>